# Create my loyalty program

Tags: magento2, reward-points

I try to create my loyalty program, use this module https://github.com/brjupo/Magento_2.4_E.E._RewardPointsGrid

I copied the code, but I get an error after "bin/magento setup:upgrade"
**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.magento_reward' doesn't exist**

why i dont have a table magento_reward?
How to finish a module? What is the best way to make a table? I will be grateful for help

```
 <?php

namespace Brjupo\RewardPointsReport\Setup\Patch\Schema;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\SchemaPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;


class CreateRewardPointsView implements SchemaPatchInterface
{

private $schemaSetup;


public function __construct(
SchemaSetupInterface $schemaSetup
){
$this->schemaSetup = $schemaSetup;
}


public function getAliases()
{
  return [];
}


public function apply()
{
$this->schemaSetup->startSetup();

$sql = "DROP VIEW IF EXISTS rewardpoints_report;";
$this->schemaSetup->getConnection()->query($sql);

$sql = "CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW rewardpoints_report AS
        (
        SELECT 
          reward_points_delta_expiration.history_id,
          customer_entity.firstname,
          customer_entity.lastname,
          customer_entity.email,
          reward_points_delta_expiration.points_delta,
          reward_points_delta_expiration.expired_at_static
        FROM
          customer_entity
        INNER JOIN
          ( SELECT 
              magento_reward_history.history_id,
              magento_reward.customer_id,
              magento_reward_history.points_delta,
              magento_reward_history.expired_at_static
            FROM
              magento_reward
            INNER JOIN magento_reward_history 
              ON magento_reward.reward_id = magento_reward_history.reward_id
          ) AS reward_points_delta_expiration 
        ON customer_entity.entity_id = reward_points_delta_expiration.customer_id
        ORDER BY reward_points_delta_expiration.history_id DESC
        );";

$this->schemaSetup->getConnection()->query($sql);
$this->schemaSetup->endSetup();


 return $this;
}
public static function getDependencies()
{
  return [];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That table is included in the Magento_Reward module which is only available in Adobe Commerce (Enterprise edition), and not available in Magento Open Source.

The module you mentioned depends on the Magento_Reward module to create Reward Points **Grid**. So you can't use that module to build the Reward Points module as you expected.

The best way to create a new table is using Declarative Schema, you can take a look at the Magento official document: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/configuration/

Comment: Patch schema not needed?

Comment: What do you mean? If you run (release) your module for the first time, you should use db_schema.xml to create a table, the link I mentioned in my answer is talking about db_schema.xml file.

Comment: If you modify your database table after that to apply a complex modification, then you should use `Schema patches` https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/patches/

Comment: thanks for the explanation

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!